# How does the app.chunk.commit.interval work in case of ItemReader<List<T>> in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have a Spring batch Application whose job is to read 2 million records from Oracle database (using Hibernate), process and update the records in the database. We are using `ItemReader<List<Employee>>` and reads all records as list but the results are restricted to 1000 (by setting `query.maxResults(1000)` in the select query).

The records will be processed one by one and updated to the database. I am using a RangePartitioner with `gridsize` 10 and `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` with `corePoolSize` 10
Now, how should I set the `app.chunk.commit.interval` in this case.I have set ot to `3` in my configuration.

I used the below ChunkListener and below is the output. Why is that the item committed is being printed as `1`. Please help me understand.

```
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemReader<List<Employee>>,ChunkListener {
@Override
public void afterChunk(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
    System.out.println("Items Read "+ chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExection().getReadCount());
    System.out.println("Items Written "+ chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExection().getWriteCount());
    System.out.println("Items Committed "+ chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExection().getCommitCount());

}

@Override
public void afterChunkError(ChunkContext chunkContext) {

}

@Override
public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
    System.out.println("Chunk processing started " + chunkContext);
}
```

}

```
Output:
Items Read  : 1
Items Written  : 1
Items Committed  : 1
```

Comment: Why are you using `ItemReader<List<Employee>>` and not `ItemReader<Employee>`? Since you defined an item as a `List<Employee>`, it looks that your `CustomItemReader` read a single item (ie a single list).

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I need to read 2 million records from the database. To avoid frequent trips to the database I am reading 1000 records at once in a list

Comment: @user2186831 if you want to avoid select query execution counts, you can do that with `List<Employee>`. In ItemReader class keep the List<Employee> field and in read() method just return List<Employee>'s element sequentially. and if List is empty execute select query and fill the list.

Comment: Quite a lot of crucial code seems to be missing from the question. Where for instance do you define the chunk size? Default is always 1 and it seems you never override this by using `chunk(3)`.

Comment: `To avoid frequent trips to the database I am reading 1000 records at once in a list `: That's not how you avoid frequent queries to the db. Both the JdbcCursorItemReader and JdbcPagingItemReader provide a setter for the fetchSize which the number of records to fetch in a single db query. So using `ItemReader<List<Employee>>` is not correct IMO. But it's up to you to define what is an item in your case (a single employee or a list of employees).

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine : I am setting the fetchSize configuration in jdbctemplate.setmaxrows(1000). I will be fetching 1000 records at once in List<Employee>. Is this a bad approach?

Comment: @Fullslack.dev I am setting the app.chunk.commit.interval to 3 in xml config

Comment: I think you really should provide more code. This current code sample which implements both `ItemReader` and `ChunkListener` is making the hairs on the back of my neck standing up.